# Is there a way to quickly gzip web asset files on Windows, to check their compressed size?

Tags: windows, shell, gzip, performance-testing

Sometimes, when doing quick size checks of HTML/CSS/JavaScript files I'm working on, I'll apply gzip compression to them on the command line on my Mac, e.g.

```
cat stylesheet.css | gzip -c | wc -c
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this on Windows? It doesn't have to be command line, although it would be nice if it was.

Comment: @devnull: looks like that’s the only suggestion! I’d be happy to accept it if you pop it in as an answer.

Comment: It's ok as a suggestion :)  (Don't take me otherwise but you may delete the post instead.  Thanks.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using any Node tools, **gzip-size-cli** is a great option.

`gzip-size path/to/file.css`

https://github.com/sindresorhus/gzip-size-cli